# Увеличение и уменьшение тональности мелодии в java android

Tags: android, аудио

Здравствуйте. Я создаю приложение под Андроид , в котором необходимо менять тон мелодии. Как можно это осуществить? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пишете на Java, то можете поискать специальные библиотеки для работой со звуком.

**Вот есть статья про Android** - [тута](https://anadea.info/ru/blog/tools-for-audio-processing-in-android-development)

**Если найти нужные библиотеки, то можете юзать матан** - [тута](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247385/)

Если ничего не подойдет, то гуглите еще вот так - **изменение частоты звука**.

***Удачи!***